# How to remove the fields for password Authentication prompt on Firebase UI Android?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

I am trying to remove the textfields for email and password authentication  at the login prompt provided with the firebase UI library at

https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android

[image]

This prompt is triggered by the following code

`mLoginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        showFirebaseLoginPrompt();
    }
});`

I just enable the Facebook AuthProvider as follows, but I still get the password authentication fields with Firebase.

`public class MainActivity extends FirebaseLoginBaseActivity {
    ...
    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        // All providers are optional! Remove any you don't want.
        setEnabledAuthProvider(AuthProviderType.FACEBOOK);
    }`

How can I achieve this?, should I modify a layout at the Firebase UI library?

Comment: try this... findViewById(R.id.facebook_button).setVisibility(View.GONE); in on create of activity method.......

Comment: This is a known [bug in FirebaseUI 0.3.1](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/issues/60). While a fix has been implemented, we haven't created a release with that fix yet. See the link for more info.